# Random spaces in sent emails

Tags: emails

I am using HTMLMailSystem to send emails from my Drupal 7 website. The problem is that random spaces appear in long emails. I have read about this and I tried the solutions on [PHP mail function randomly adds a space to message text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14762679/1059672).

I added the following code in my module's `hook_mail_alter()`, but it didn't help.

```
$message['body'][0] = chunk_split(base64_encode($message['body'][0]));
$message['headers']['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'base64';
```

I also tried using `wordwrap()`, and spaces are gone, but result is pretty ugly.

How can I fix this issue?

I am also using the Mailmime module, if that is relevant.

Comment: What's actually causing the spaces? Is it HTML? CSS? Line breaks? You'll be able to tell by looking at the raw source

Comment: HTML is base64 encoded, so I can't really see anything. In object inspector it looks like a space character.

Comment: Just decode it and view it in a browser, that'll tell you. Multiple whitespace is collapsed in HTML so if it's an HTML email, and you're using a good client, you should never see multiple consecutive spaces. Which might suggest the spaces aren't spaces. But you'll need to look at the actual HTML to know for sure